# Is it possible to change the default telephone calling app for another of different brand?

Tags: samsung, system-apps, lg-g4

I want to use the telephone calling/SMS app that I have in a LG G4 in a Samsung S9.

Is it that possible?

The LG G4 has a feature that the Samsung app doesn't have and I use a lot.

Comment: You can try to extract the APK from the LG phone and side-load the APK to your different phone.

Comment: Unless the app depends on its system framework, it should run normally. In addition to Robert's "extracting APK" method, you can also check the package name and then search & download from APK mirror sites if available.

Comment: @Robert What do you mean with "side-load"? Do I need to have my new phone rooted? The old LG app can't be installed as a normal app like some people do with the launcher?

Comment: @AndrewT. That's is what I don't know, I think that the phone/SMS app is more than one executable running at same time.

Comment: Side-load means installing an app outside from Google Play Store, e.g. by downloading the APK file and installing it directly or via `adb install`. Root is not required.